# Flutter: How to return data?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code. And i want to return my data `memo_list`. `memo_list` have value in code of `here`.

But `memo_list` is return empty value.

I don't know why data has been removed.

```
  List fetchMemosFromAllUsers(List<dynamic> users){
    List memo_list = List();

    for(final user in users){
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("MEMO").where(KEY_USERKEY, isEqualTo: user).get().then((docs) {
        if(docs.docs.isNotEmpty){
          for(int i = 0; i < docs.docs.length; i++){
            memo_list.add(docs.docs[i].data());         <-------here
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return memo_list;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not awaiting for the Future to return. memo_list is returned before .then() is executed, therefore memo_list will always be empty.

Try

```
  Future<List> fetchMemosFromAllUsers(List<dynamic> users) async {
    List memo_list = List();

    for(final user in users){
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("MEMO").where(KEY_USERKEY, isEqualTo: user).get().then((docs) {
        if(docs.docs.isNotEmpty){
          for(int i = 0; i < docs.docs.length; i++){
            memo_list.add(docs.docs[i].data());         <-------here
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return memo_list;
  }
```